# Does the class have unnecessary and violating Single responsibility principle method?

Tags: c#, collections, factory-method

I encountered with the following code in the work. The `MyItemCoordinator` should receive `MyItem` objects, process them, add them to `MyItemList` collection and then pass them to the listeners.

My questions are:

1. When I saw `NewMyItem` method I thought that `MyItemCoordinator` is a factory but when I saw `NewMyItem`'s implementation I found out that it creates, sorts, calling to listeners and it's not `static`. So `MyItemCoordinator` is not a factory and `NewMyItem` method does way more things that it should to do according to its name, right?
2. If it's not a factory so why `NewMyItem` method receives so many params, creates an object, adds to the collection? Why not to do:

   example:

   ```
   var coordinator = new MyItemCoordinator();
   var myItem = new MyItem(...PARAMS..)
   coordinator.AddMyItemToList(myItem)
   ```

   Inside `AddMyItemToList` we can sort and call the listeners. This is more clear way to do, isn't it?
3. So, is this implementation correct? Doesn't it have something wrong?

   ```
   public class MyItemCoordinator
   {    
       ...

       public IList<MyItem> MyItemList = new List<MyItem>();

       public void NewMyItem(int id, ...15_MORE_PARAMS)
       {
           MyItem myItem = new MyItem(id,...ONLY_5_PARAMS_WITHIN_15_ARE_USED);
           AddMyItemToList(myItem);
           SortMyItemList();
           if (MyItemDetectedHandler != null)
               MyItemDetectedHandler(this);
       }

       public void AddMyItemToList(MyItem myItem)
       {
           //makes some checking and adds myItem to MyItemList
       }

       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: `MyItemList` allows direct manipulation of the internal state, bypassing `AddMyItemToList` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, but you should take this to its logical conclusion.

- Creating item belongs to a factory class.
- Tracking a list of items (coordinating?) is another responsibility.
- Handling the new item (or list? Not clear from the code) belongs to a third class.

With this design you can reliability test each component in isolation. Merging these responsibilities into a single class makes testing difficult and blocks alternate implementations.

Comment: I agree that creating item can be moved to a factory class, but as it's implemented here with `NewMyItem` it's wrong. In addition, it's not a factory, right?